# VBA: Sorting worksheets with macro

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

As shown in this image

[image: This is a picture of the error]

My sort syntax is wrong and I don't understand why.

I get

> Run-time error '1004': The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.

```
Sub Sort()
'
' Sort Macro

Dim rowNum As Variant

Dim columnNum As Variant
Dim sortField As Range
Dim keySort As Range

rowNum = Worksheets("Updated 1.0").Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
MsgBox (rowNum)

columnNum = Worksheets("Updated 1.0").Range("A1").End(xlToRight).column
MsgBox (columnNum)

With Worksheets("Updated 1.0")
    Set sortField = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(rowNum, columnNum))
    Set keySort = Range("A1")
    sortField.Sort Key1:=keySort, Order1:=xlDescending, MatchCase:=False, 
Orientation:=xlSortRows

End With
```

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - that's something I've been wondering about since I saw a question with an unqualified range.  If both cell references within the unqualified range are qualified then the range is also qualified.  With a different sheet selected  the parent of `sortfield` is still `Updated 1.0`.  After saying that - it's still, better to fully qualify everything.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook In the code-behind for `Sheet1`, doing `Range(Sheet2.Cells(1,1) = 42` throws error 1004. Same in the code-behind for `ThisWorkbook`, and ditto in a standard module. In the code-behind for `Sheet1`, doing `Range(Sheet2.Cells(1,1), Sheet2.Cells(2,1)) = 42` throws error 1004 (because of the implicit `Me` qualifier), but works in `ThisWorkbook` and in a standard module. You know what, IMO that's knowledge that's dangerous to share (being confusing for inexperienced VBA devs). Qualify your ranges, period - then your code will work regardless of where & how it's written. ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Point well made and something I hadn't considered.  I'm sure I'd read somewhere about the implicit `Me` qualifier when used behind a sheet, but had forgotten as I always qualify the ranges.

Answer (score 2):

You were missing some `.` inside the `With` but also the sort was was not correct I think.

This worked for me:

```
Sub Sort()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim sortField As Range
    Dim keySort As Range

    Set sht = Worksheets("Updated 1.0")

    With sht
        Set sortField = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set keySort = .Range("A1")
        sortField.Sort Key1:=keySort, Order1:=xlDescending, MatchCase:=False, _
                       Orientation:=xlSortRows
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but it still did not correct the error for the sort line in the with block